# How to insert a linebreak at the cursor position

Tags: vim

To insert a linebreak at the current cursor position, I usually do:

<kbd>i</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd><kbd>escape</kbd>

Is there a shorter way to do this? Something like `o` that would add the linebreak immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There unfortunately isn't...

But you can always create a mapping to make it faster:

```
nnoremap go i<CR><ESC>
```